What is the industry-specific name for this type of window?

Like the title asks, I’m looking for the industry-specific name for this type of window. Thanks in advance!

What you have in the picture are two  1/4 eyebrow arch windows.

I've heard these by a number of names and even manufacturers are not consistent in terminology. Quarter-circle, Arch(ed), radius, and quarter-moon  are all terms used.
Where I am located, Quarter-circle is the most common term, but radius, arch(ed), quarter-moon are pretty common too. Radius and arched can also refer to half-circle style windows as well.
